# moving the list view infoormation to a page

Tags: android, android-intent

all i want is that when the user presses on a a specific list item the   the text from the list view goes to another page and shows the information in a   text view

this is my list view page

```
    public class usernews extends AppCompatActivity {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("allNews").child("allNews");


        ProgressBar loading;
        private ListView lsStudents;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_usernews);
             loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
            lsStudents=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



            Toast.makeText(usernews.this,
                     "يرجى التأكد من أنك متصل بالإنترنت إذالم تكن متصل بعد...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {



                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.


                    final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    // Get value from areaSnapShot not from dataSnapshot
                        String value1 = String.valueOf(areaSnapshot.getValue());
                        areas.add(value1);
                        if (lsStudents.equals(null)){
                            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                        if (!lsStudents.equals(null)){
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        }

                    }


                    String value2 = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());






                   ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(usernews.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, areas);
                    lsStudents.setAdapter(areasAdapter);







                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Toast.makeText(usernews.this,
                           error + "!!!!!خطاء في الاتصال !!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

/* any help*/

Comment: i dont have any error but my problem is i dont know how

Comment: Then I misunderstood and I am sorry.

Comment: i have a well working list view i just want to show the information of the list view item in a text view when i click it

Comment: no problem man i just want to know how to do it